# How do I get the Picture in a Shape?

Tags: excel, office-interop, excel-interop

After I call:

```
Shape shape = tag.TagRange.Worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture(filename,
MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue,
tag.TagRange.Left / 20f, tag.TagRange.Top / 20f, width / 20f, height / 20f);
```

How do I get the Picture object from the created shape? I need to use this instead of Pictures.Insert() because Insert() creates a link to the picture instead of copying it into the XLSX file.

Note: I am using the COM API for my AddIn, not VSTO.

Comment: I don't find a `Picture` or `Pictures` object in the Excel object model? Which version of Excel is this?

Comment: Hi Cindy. Look for Worksheet.Pictures(), it returns a Picture. Although I'm hoping there's a property in Shape that can get me to it. thanks - dave